# JQuery expand and contract div on click

Tags: jquery, html, expand, contract

I'm trying to use jQuery to expand and contract the height of a div when a link is clicked, and I can't for the life of me work out what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the html;

```
<div id="slider" class="map">
    <div id="map-canvas">this is a test</div>
</div>

<div id="slider-map"><a href="#" id="expand">Expand +</a></div>
```

The slider height is 300px by default in the CSS

Here's the jQuery;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var maxWidth = 500;
    var minWidth = 300;

    $("#expand").click(
        function(){
            var curHeight = $("#slider").height();
            if(curHeight==300)
            {
                $("#slider").animate({height: maxWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
                $("#expand").html("Contract <small style='font-size:12px;'>-</small>");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#slider").animate({height: minWidth+"px"}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
                $("#expand").html("Expand <small style='font-size:12px;'>+</small>");
            }
        return false;
    });
}
```

I've tried this without calling the Google maps API in the map-canvas div too see if that was the culprit, but it still won't work.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Does #slider have overflow: hidden applied to it in your CSS? Also you dont need to declare the new height as maxWidth+"px", just maxWidth is fine.

Comment: You forgot to close the $(document).ready properly. replace } with });

Comment: Did'nt realise I could omit the "px" thanks for that, although it still won't work. The only styles applied to #slider are margins, and #slider.map height:300px; width:100%;

Comment: Wow do I feel stupid, that missing bracket was the culprit. Thanks!

Comment: bananabread wasn't the one who mentioned it.. o.O

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the $(document).ready(); function

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var maxWidth = 500;
    var minWidth = 300;

    $("#expand").click(

        function(){
            var curHeight = $("#slider").height();
            alert(curHeight);
            if(curHeight==300)
            {
                $("#slider").animate({height: maxWidth}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
                $("#expand").html("Contract <small style='font-size:12px;'>-</small>");
            }
            else
            {
                $("#slider").animate({height: minWidth}, { queue:false, duration:400 });
                $("#expand").html("Expand <small style='font-size:12px;'>+</small>");
            }
        return false;
    });
});
```

css:

```
.map
{
    background-color:green;
}

<div id="slider" class="map">
    <div id="map-canvas">this is a test</div>
</div>
```

html:

```
<div id="slider-map"><a href="#" id="expand">Expand +</a></div>
```

works for me. tested in chrome ;)